# Flume-ng Spool directory source polling directory for new files instead of using native WatchService API

Tags: hadoop, flume

I was digging into the Flume-ng's `SpoolingDirectorySource` src and found that it polls the spool directory after the specified `POLL_DELAY_MS` parameter to generate new events. These events are then handled by `ReliableSpoolingFileEventReader` in a seperate thread.

I was wondering why `ReliableSpoolingFileEventReader` does not use `WatchService` API, which is pretty low level as well as thread-safe. Is there any specific design constraint which favored polling over watcher? \

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Flume works better with batches of events. This is because the File channel `fsync`s for every batch. Thus, waiting for a period of time is a good trade-off to collect a batch of events.